# Moving an Appended Div tag up and down using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a to do app for my final project. The problem I am having is I would like the div tags to be able to be moved up or down an element depending on what the user clicks. I can make this work with preexisting div tags, but appended div tags the code falls apart. Any insight would greatly be appreciated. I have the code up on codepen so I will provide a link there and I will also display my code here.

```
$('#addTask').click(function(){
   var task = $('#taskadd').val();
     var date = $('#datepicker').val();
        $('<div id="items"><div class="card-header"><span class="up" id="up"></span><span class="down" id="down"></span><p>Due Date:'+date+'</p><p>Task:'+task+'</p><div></div>').appendTo('.container').slideDown('slow');;
     resetModal();
     counter++;
   });
    var selected=0;

     var itemlist = $('#items');
    var len=$(itemlist).children().length; 
    console.log(len);

    $(document).on('click', '#items div',function(){
        selected= counter;

        alert("Selected item is " + selected);
    });

  $(document).on('click', '#up',function(e){

       e.preventDefault();
       if(selected>0)
        {

            jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected-1)).before(jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected)));
            selected=selected-1;
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#down',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        if(selected < len)
        {
            jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected+1)).after(jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected)));
            selected=selected+1;
        }
    });



});
```

My codepen is:http://codepen.io/louis345/pen/dOqdQW.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Hopefully my issue is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not use IDs for multiple elements, use classes instead (talking about `#up` and `#down`).

In jQuery try to get currently clicked element, clone it, then add it above or below prev/next element, while removing original element. You can change you arrow links to use classes like so `<span class="arrows moveUp"></span>` and `<span class="arrows moveDown"></span>`

```
$(".arrows").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var task = (this).parent();
  var currentElement = task.clone(true);
  if ( $(this).hasClass("moveUp") && task.prev().length > 0 ) {
    task.prev().before(currentElement);
  } else if ( $(this).hasClass("moveDown") && task.next().length > 0 ) {
    task.next().after(currentElement);
  }
  task.remove();
});
```

Comment: I don't want to clone the element. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: But you can clone it and remove the original element and keeping all its properties and events attached previously.